# onpageshow is not firing after back second time iOS 6+

Tags: javascript, ios, events

The issue is that `onpageshow` (the same with `onpagehide`) is not firing after back for the second time.

Test case:

1. Go to page XXX and click link for YYY page.
2. Back to previous page. Event `onpageshow` **will** fire.
3. Click link for YYY page.
4. Back to previous page once again. Event `onpageshow` **won't** fire.

Why? How to force `onpageshow` to fire?

*Ps. Note that I don't want solution how to make `onpageshow` works, because it's working, but only once.*